# How to protect my SharePoint site from attack

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, anonymous-authentication

I have a new SharePoint site with anonymous access enabled and plan for it to be published over the internet.

I have heard the anonymous is very risky and exposes you to attacks, is that correct?

Could you please tell me how can I protect the SharePoint site from attacks?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**By default,** SharePoint is secure! Generally, your farm should be up to date with security fixes that bundled with the MU or the CU.

**Sharegate** wrote a good article about [How to make SharePoint Secure.](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/10-ways-make-sharepoint-secure) that summarized as the following:

- Run the Microsoft Security Assessment Tool & Best Practice Security Analyzer Tool from Microsoft
- Only enable the required Windows Services where you need them.
- Only enable the required SharePoint Services where you want them to run.
- Create multiple Service Accounts, that do not have Domain or Server Administration Permission
- Use DNS URLs, not Server name for access
- Only use known ports for access, such as 80 or 443, then control access via Firewalls
- Do not disable the Windows Server Firewall
- Utilize the “ViewFormPagesLockdown” feature
- Protect external entry points via firewall rules
- Allow Permissions only at the levels where needed, Farm, Service, Web, Site Collection, Site, and Content,.

**Also check the below good references**

- [Thinking like a Hacker to help Secure SharePoint](https://www.itprotoday.com/file-sharing-and-management/thinking-hacker-help-secure-sharepoint)
- [6 SharePoint Security Challenges](https://www.darkreading.com/risk-management/6-sharepoint-security-challenges/d/d-id/1100532)